# There exists a ball inside the convex hull of the union of $2$ other balls

Tags: normed-spaces, alternative-proof, convex-geometry

I'm trying to show that given a point in the line segment connecting centers of $2$ given balls, there is a ball centered at that point inside the convex hull of the union of that $2$ other balls.

Could you have a check on my attempt? Is there other approach to this problem?

---

> Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space, $a,b\in X$, and $r_a , r_b \ge0$. Let $B_a$ (resp. $B_b$) be the open ball centered at $a$ (resp. $b$) with radius $r_a$ (resp. $r_b$). We fix $0 < \lambda < 1$ and let $c:=\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$ and $r_c:=\lambda r_a + (1-\lambda)r_b$. Then
> $$
> B_c \subset \operatorname{conv} (B_a \cup B_b).
> $$

**My attempt:** Let $x_c \in B_c$ such that $x_c \neq c$. Consider
$$
x_a := a + \lambda_a (x_c - c) \quad \text{and} \quad x_b := b + \lambda_b (x_c - c)
$$
for some $\lambda_a, \lambda_b >0$. We succeed if we can find $\lambda_a, \lambda_b$ such that
$$
x_a \in B_a, \quad x_b \in B_b, \quad x_c = \lambda x_a + (1-\lambda)x_b,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\|x_a-a\| \le r_a, \quad \|x_b-b\| \le r_b, \quad x_c = \lambda x_a + (1-\lambda)x_b.
$$

These conditions are equivalent to
$$
\lambda_a \le \frac{r_a}{\|x_c-c\|}, \quad \lambda_b \le \frac{r_b}{\|x_b-b\|}, \quad \lambda_a\lambda+\lambda_b(1-\lambda)= 1.
$$

Notice that
$$
\frac{r_a}{\|x_c-c\|} \lambda+ \frac{r_b}{\|x_b-b\|} (1-\lambda) \ge \lambda + (1-\lambda)= 1.
$$

So such $\lambda_a, \lambda_b$ do exist. This completes the proof.

Comment: I believe you want to have $\|x_c-c\|$ everywhere in the denominator (and not $\|x_b-b\|$).

Comment: Thank you so much @MatthiasKlupsch. You're right.